# C# - How add new items to list with parallel tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Hi Im trying to get information from a large list of object. This is my code:

```
List<Foo> Information = new List<Foo>();
List<string> SubPaths =  getPaths(); //about 10000
var SplittedList = splitList(SubPaths, 100); //100 list of 100 (100*100=10000)

foreach(var list in SplittedList)
{
    List<Foo> ProcessedList = DoSomethingWithParallelTasks(list); 
    Information.AddRange(ProcessedList); //when one of all task finished
}

Int number = Information.Count()//test: number = 10000
```

How can i get the information from multiple list and add this information to one list.

If i process the list in the normal way It takes more than an hour. @Mark Baijens

```
    List<Foo> Information = new List<Foo>();
     List<string> SubPaths = getPaths(); //about 10000 
        foreach(var path in SubPaths ) { 

Information.Add(DoSomethingWithoutParallelTask(path);

        }
```

It takes more than an hour

Thanks.

Comment: Question unclear. You will need to transform the strings into Foo since you want to put lists of strings into one list of Foo. And you want to do this parallel so multi treaded?

Comment: If i process the list in the normal way It takes more than an hour. `List<Foo> Information = new List<Foo>();
List<string> SubPaths =  getPaths(); //about 10000

foreach(var path in SubPaths )
{
    Information.Add(DoSomethingWithoutParallelTask(path);
}` It takes more than an hour

Comment: Still unsure what you mean, but I think you might want to look into parallel foreach function. (multi threading). Be careful though since multi treading can lead into complicated problems if you don't know what you are doing. You might wan't to do more research on that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this. I don't know that much about multi treading so i recommend to do more research on it before implementing in a live environment since multi treading can lead into unreliable code if programmed in the wrong way.

```
Parallel.ForEach(SubPaths, (currentPath) => {
    Information.Add(DoSomethingWithoutParallelTask(currentPath);
});
```